# Should the Fate series become one tag?

Tags: discussion, lumping-and-splitting

To be honest, I don't watch the whole Fate series so I don't really know how to deal with this, but watching Fate/stay night and Fate/Zero, it seems like these are two separate series set in the same universe since Fate/Zero is a prequel for Fate/stay night.

And I want to add some detail in the tag wiki for fate-series, so before I do that, I want to make sure whether this tag should be one tag or not.

And now we have four Fate tags: [fate-stay-night](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-stay-night) [fate-zero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-zero) [fate-extra](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-extra) and [fate-kaleid-liner](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-kaleid-liner).

Comment: Probably not. From what I've read about them, they're all different despite having similarities. Something like Final Fantasy perhaps. Anyway, they have different titles, so it's probably better to let them have different tags in long term.

Comment: yeah I thought so, I just want to make sure, but fate zero and fate stay night are same despite they have different title, and from what I watch, fate kaleid is different, I don't know about the others

Comment: In this case it's still better to keep different tags so you don't have to explain why 2 series share 1 tag and the rest have their own tags, when they all have a common name.

Comment: perhaps a "nasuverse" for general Type-Moon and Nasu Kinoko related series?